# Optimized way to extract patches based on bounding box in PyTorch

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, bounding-box

Assuming we got tensors: `img` and bounding boxes: `bbox` of shape:

```
[B, C, H, W], [B, xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], respectively
```

Is there an optimized way to extract the corresponding patches from each tensor(each tensor has a different bounding box) via PyTorch or Python?
Due to the fact that I want to build a real-time application all my tries were really slow regarding this.

Comment: If your bounding boxes are not uniform, it's unlikely you would have a vectorized solution. Your best bet would just be an optimized `for` loop.

Comment: "all my tries were really slow" show us one of them

Comment: You could probably create a masked version of `img` in a vectorized/batched way, but torch doesn't have support for ragged tensors, so you'd need to iterate manually as @QuangHoang mentions